# Best way to keep an ordered list of windows (from most-recently created to oldest)?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to manage a list of windows (keeping them in order) to be able to promote the next window to the top-level when the current top-level window is closed.
This is for a web application, so we're using jQuery Javascript.

We'd talked through a few simplistic solutions, such as using an array and just treating [0] index as the top-most window.

I'm wondering if there's any potentially more efficient or useful alternative to what we had brainstormed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stack if you want to just close the window on top.
A queue if you also need to open windows at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know javascript, but couldn't you create a stack of windows?

Answer (score 1):

Stack/queue in JS is a simple array, which can be manipulated with `.push(val)`, `.pop()`, `.shift(val)` and `.unshift()`.